# I have an issue running an imported project on flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Process terminated unexpectedly.

initial content not found

Launch command details:  `"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4\sdks\4.0.0\bin\adl.exe" -runtime "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4\sdks\4.0.0\runtimes\air\win" "C:\Users\acer\Adobe Flash Builder 4\Dental Clinic_2\Main-app.xml" "C:\Users\acer\Adobe Flash Builder 4\Dental Clinic_2"`

I get this error when I try to run the program...this is my first time to import other projects.. I dont have this problem with my own program this just appeared from the project I imported...could someone help me..

Comment: How do you run the program?  Where did you get the project that you tried to import?  What did you import the project into? ( Flash Builder?)  Were there any errors when you tried to import?  Have you tried to specify the SDK for the imported project?  Have you tried to recompile the imported project?

Comment: Check that the AIR SDK version you used in the SDK is the same as defined in the application descriptor

Answer (score 1):

change application tag and version to 1.5:

Answer (score 1):

[image: Flex Won't Run Error]

```
Process terminated without establishing connection to debugger.
Invalid application descriptor. Unknown http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.1
```

I could not get any flex air project to run in my flash builder, changing this line in the Main-app.xml allowed the project to run. Something about flex air requiring a minimum of the 2.6 SDK to run, even though I am going through the flash 4.5.1 SDK.

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.6">
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error when I was developing a mobile application in Flash Builder 4.7 (Flex 4.6.0, Air 3.5). It turned out that **auto-formatting the application-descriptor XML-file**  (Main-app.xml) was the problem.

In an application-descriptor XML-file there should be a `<content>` element like

```
    <!-- The main SWF or HTML file of the application. Required. -->
    <!-- Note: In Flash Builder, the SWF reference is set automatically. -->
    <content>[This value will be overwritten by Flash Builder in the output app.xml]</content>
```

Now when the application is built the build-script copies the application-descriptor to the output directory (for examle bin-debug) and should replace the contents of the `<content>` element with the name of the generated SWF-file, for example `<content>Main.swf</content>`.

After auto-formatting the application-descriptor (pressing [ctrl] + [shift] + [F] in Flashbuilder) the element looked like

```
    <!-- The main SWF or HTML file of the application. Required. -->
    <!-- Note: In Flash Builder, the SWF reference is set automatically. -->
    <content>[This value will be overwritten by Flash Builder in 
        the output app.xml]
    </content>
```

Note the linebreaks that have been inserted within and after the text-contents.

Now the build-script was no longer able to replace the text-contents with the name of the SWF-file. So in the resulting application-descriptor in the output folder (bin-debug) the `<content>` element still contained the formatted place-holder content. Hence the SWF-file could not be found and the *'initial content not found'* error occured.